# why B frame only 50:1 compression ratio, but h264 can have 250:1 compression ratio?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, video-codecs, video-compression

I'm learning some knowledge about video coding and now I know I frame has about 7:1 compression ration, P frame has about 20:1 compression ratio, B frame has 50:1 compression ratio, but why h264 has 250:1 compression ratio, it seems it uses some extra efficient algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Your ratios are incorrect. The perframe compression ratio is highly depend on the content itself. For example an all black frame will compress MUCH better than 7:1 and white noise will be difficult to compress more that 1:1 without looking blocky.

Yes, h264 is pretty good at its job, but not because of “an algorithm” there are dozens of different algorithms and techniques that combine to produce the results.